# How to calculate the risk neutral probability of the underlying price always exceeding the lower barrier K during a given time?

Tags: options, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to price the autocallable structured products by a probability approach proposed in the following paper: *Modeling autocallable structured products*, by Geng Deng, Joshua Mallett, Craig McCann (2011) https://link.springer.com/article/10.1057/jdhf.2011.25

I'd like to add another feather that the monitoring of knock-in is continuous during the lifetime of the product, so I need to find the probability of the underlying asset price never exceeds the lower barrier, but I do not know how to handle with the problem. Could you guys provide some insights? Thanks!